# Python 2 Max Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, max

Here is my code

```
def max_array_diff(line):
    return max(line)

line = raw_input().split()
print max_array_diff(line)
print line
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
9
['1', '9', '2', '-7', '10', '4', '3']
```

I need my output to be 10. raw_input() is coming in as a string, I have converted it to a list and am trying to get the max value from it but it keeps returning 9 instead of 10. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's doing exactly what it should be doing, '9' > '10' but 10 > 9. You need to cast the values of the list to integers before comparing them

Answer (score 7):

You should convert the input to integers after splitting them; otherwise you'd be doing string comparisons with `max()`.

Change:

```
line = raw_input().split()
```

to:

```
line = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Alternatively, you can specify `int` as the `key` function for `max()` so that comparisons would be made based on the integer values of the string inputs.

Change:

```
return max(line)
```

to:

```
return max(line, key=int)
```

Comment: can you explain what map is doing please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do integer compare instead of string compare:

```
def max_array_diff(line):
    return max(line)

line = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]
print max_array_diff(line)
print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Or another way is to do:

```
print(sorted(raw_input().split(),key=int))
```

To get the highest do:

```
print(sorted(raw_input().split(),key=int)[0])
```

To get Top 3:

```
print(sorted(raw_input().split(),key=int)[:3])
```